# how to solve this mean stack application error

Tags: mean-stack

I am designing an application using the steps given in the [link](http://www.mean.io/#!/docs)

I want to place my static html pages in my project using mean stack, when i compiling the code, i am getting the following error,

```
 ReferenceError: Myapp is not defined
 at C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\server\routes\index.js:11:6
 at callbacks (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My  Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
 at param (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
 at pass (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
 at Router._dispatch (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
 at Object.router (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
at next (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
 at Object.handle (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\connect-flash\lib\flash.js:21:5)
 at next (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
 at Object.Meanio.chainware.before [as handle] (C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\My Documents\GitHub\ssit\node_modules\meanio\lib\mean0.3.2.js:322:41)
```

how could i resolve this error.

Comment: Are you in the same directory where you launched "init myApp"?

Comment: yes i am running the app from the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about checking your app.js(@public\js\app.js)

add like this.

> angular.module('mean', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'mean.system', 'mean.articles', **'mean.Myapp'** ]);
>
> angular.module('mean.system', []);
>   angular.module('mean.articles', []);
>   **> angular.module('mean.Myapp', []);**